# Halting an OSC UDP listener function. Xcode iOS application

Tags: c++, c, xcode, udp, osc

I'm developing an application that sends OSC data via UDP between a host program and an iPad. Sending from the iPad to the host program was reasonably straight forward. However,  receiving data from host program on the iPad has been more troublesome.

I have got to a point where the iPad is RECEIVING the data, but becomes stuck in the .run() packet listener function. It was my understanding that a .break() would interrupt the function and return to my main program, but it doesn't seem to work.

I am more experienced working with objective-c in an iOS environment, so it may be my rudimentary understanding of C++ that is letting me down.

Code below: (I have been using the oscPack library to produce this code. Available Here: http://www.rossbencina.com/code/oscpack)

in my main function (Where the break() points don't appear to be working):

```
ExamplePacketListener listener;
UdpListeningReceiveSocket s(
            IpEndpointName( IpEndpointName::ANY_ADDRESS, RECEIVEPORT ),
            &listener );

s.RunUntilSigInt();
//s.Run();
s.Break();
s.AsynchronousBreak();
```

My packet listener class, very similar to the oscPack example. With some argument modifications. This was another area I felt could be causing a problem. If my osc messages aren't padded correctly, could it stop the run() function from being returned?

```
class ExamplePacketListener : public osc::OscPacketListener {
protected:

virtual void ProcessMessage( const osc::ReceivedMessage& m,
                            const IpEndpointName& remoteEndpoint )
{
    (void) remoteEndpoint; // suppress unused parameter warning

    try{
        // example of parsing single messages. osc::OsckPacketListener
        // handles the bundle traversal.

        if( std::strcmp( m.AddressPattern(), "/oscMasterSend" ) == 0 ){
            // example #1 -- argument stream interface
            osc::ReceivedMessageArgumentStream args = m.ArgumentStream();

            bool a1;
            args >> a1 >> osc::EndMessage;
            NSLog(@"%d",a1);

        }
    }
}
};
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Tom.

Comment: Set some 'stop' boolean flag and send the listener an empty datagram on local stack to wake up the listener so it can check the flag.

Comment: @MartinJames, thanks for the feedback. I'm not sure I'm following though, do you mean a stop flag within the class?

Comment: Yes, call some stop() member function that sets the flag and sends the datagram.